# Nesting MAX() function inside IIF()?

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions, iif

I have nested `IIF()` functions in my select statement, and inside of each a nested `MAX()`.  It seems to want me to include this select statement in the GROUP BY.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.employee_id, 
IIF(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt=max(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt),"Last Wk",
  IIF(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt=max(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt)-7,"2 Wks Ago",
    IIF(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt=max(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt)-14,"3 Wks Ago",
      IIF(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt=max(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt)-21,"4 Wks Ago")))),
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.hrs_worked, 
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.move_count, 
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.moves_per_hour

FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl
WHERE d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt In (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 wk_ending_dt 
FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl
ORDER BY wk_ending_dt DESC)

GROUP BY 
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.employee_id,
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.move_count, 
d2s_loader_performance_tbl.moves_per_hour
```

When I run, I get this error: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression [lists the chunk that is the nested IIFs] as part of an aggregate function.  When I put this in the GROUP BY (which doesn't make sense), I get this error: "Cannot have aggregate function in GROUP BY clause"

So what in the H-E-double hockey sticks does access want me to do?  The point of this is turning week-ending dates into a relative term.  This report gets updated weekly, and I am tired of manually going through all my queries and reports and changing the references to new dates.

Thank you!

Comment: What format are the dates in?

Comment: When I open the table in design view, Data Type is "Date/Time", and within Field Properties "Format" is left blank. Would there be a functional difference between choosing Short Date vs Long Date?

Comment: Query runs right, gifing 12/28/13.  Then I try this `SELECT Max(wk_ending_dt) AS MaxOfwk_ending_dt,
Max(wk_ending_dt) - 7 AS MaxOfwk_ending_dt7
FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl` to test the math, and that works as well--I get 2 columns, 12/28/13 and 12/21/13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about putting part of your query into a sub-select (or maybe even a separate query).  Like this:

```
SELECT 
  orig.employee_id, 
  IIF(orig.wk_ending_dt=PreAgg.max_wk_ending_dt),"Last Wk",
    IIF(orig.wk_ending_dt=PreAgg.max_wk_ending_dt)-7,"2 Wks Ago",
      IIF(orig.wk_ending_dt=PreAgg.max_wk_ending_dt)-14,"3 Wks Ago",
        IIF(orig.wk_ending_dt=PreAgg.max_wk_ending_dt)-21,"4 Wks Ago")))),
  orig.hrs_worked, 
  orig.move_count, 
  orig.moves_per_hour
FROM (
  SELECT 
  d2s_loader_performance_tbl.employee_id, 
  max(d2s_loader_performance_tbl.wk_ending_dt) AS Max_wk_ending_dt

  FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl

  GROUP BY 
  d2s_loader_performance_tbl.employee_id
) PreAgg JOIN d2s_loader_performance_tbl AS orig ON
PreAgg.employee_id=orig.employee_id

WHERE orig.wk_ending_dt In (
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 4 wk_ending_dt 
  FROM d2s_loader_performance_tbl
  ORDER BY wk_ending_dt DESC)
```

Comment: After some tweaking I got your first suggestion to work just as I saw your edit go through.  One important note is the WHERE statement in this has to go in the parent query.  It looks to me that the WHERE in the sub-query restricts the choices for the MAX value--unnecessary as the MAX value is the same whether I choose all values or limit to top _n_ values.  Rather, it needs the WHERE at the end to restrict the "master pull". Great suggestion!

Comment: Yes.  Good point about the WHERE clause.  I will correct it, above.  Thanks.